# Is there some standard or virtually standard way to document code in a language agnostic and IDE agnostic fashion?

Tags: documentation, communication, standards, industry-standard

In java we generally do it the java-docs way and in js the popular method these days is vscode documentation using `@param, @returns, @example` etc but I would prefer if there were some language agnostic and IDE agnostic way to do so; probably, backed by some RFC; anyways, the most I can come up with is using markdown which seems to work for me but I'm not sure that's why reaching community to find out if we already have some standard way to do this

anyways the following

````
/**
 * returns random string of *length* e.g. generateRandomString(6) can return 'fi3Y0s'
 * 
 * - **Parameters**:
 *   - `length` {number}: required length of random string 
 * 
 * - **Returns**:
 *   - {string}: string consisting of random characters and having length provided by _length_ parameter
 * 
 * - **Example**
 *   ```javascript
 *   generateRandomString(6)
 *   //fi3Y0s
 *   ```
 */
function generateRandomString(length) {
  // implementation goes here
}
````

would yield this is vscode which is convincing enough
[image]

which kind of works except the function definition line still show wrong parameter type but it's okay; now, apart from this I'd like to know if I can do better so that other developers are also cool with it

**What I tried:** googling, chatgpt (that's where I got the markdown idea); there were guides but about what to document rather than about how to type this documentation; also I could not find any RFC on this, Now my expectation is some RFC if exists or some unspoken virtual standard which is shared by the community, something backed by open-source standards

*(I didn't ask this question on stackoverflow because if was hinted to be subjective, just wanted to confirm if there's already something existing just like REST standards and I'm just not aware about it)*

Comment: What are you looking for? What you describe are comments. Specific tools can parse source files, extract comments, and turn those into documentation. However, finding and recommending tools is off-topic here.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'm not looking for a tool I'm looking for a standard if it exists and if no standard/specification like SQL, REST, Markdown exists for documentation of code then my search ends here, I no more need to look for it then; I'll just use the best thing which makes sense to me, if you still think it's off-topic I'll take this down

Comment: There is no language agnostic syntax for embedding non-code information in code so any parsing tool would inherently be language specific. Additionally the concepts required to document code vary widely by language. Trying to document a class in Rust for example would be nonsensical, whilst a Typeclass would be nonsensical in java. Likewise in dynamic languages documenting the types that are expected and returned is important, in statically typed language you expect that from the typesystem and a good documentation tool should be able to autogenerate that information.

Comment: Overall there is significant benefit to specializing the documentation format to match the needs of the language, and minimal benefit to standardization.

Comment: Why exactly are you asking this? Just for curiosity? Or are you working in a real-world environment which uses a list of certain languages, and you want a standard which fits to them all? If it is the former, I think the question is not a good fit for the site and should be closed (though it is not off-topic, it needs more focus). If it is the latter, then tell us the list of language and which real-world problems you have with the current way of documenting your code.

Comment: @DocBrown for me step-1 "give it a try can it work" step-2 "fill the database" step-3 "generate programs based on those documentations/interfaces which can run in different environment but with a common interface so that you collect ready-made parts from different language code-bases"

Comment: I take that as "just for curiosity".

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard. It all depends on the specific tool that you use for generating the documentation.

On one hand, you have language-specific tools like [Javadoc for Java](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html), [Scaladoc for Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html), [rdoc for Ruby](https://github.com/ruby/rdoc), and [pydoc for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html), to give a few examples. You also have tools that support multiple languages, like [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/).

You need to consider your environment and choose the appropriate tool(s). If I need a documentation generator, I start with a tool that comes with the language, if one exists.

Comment: thanks @Thomas, I think Doxygen you mentioned is something language agnostic, I'll definitely look into that but now I have a feeling that maybe we as a community have not yet thought of cornering this topic towards a specific end so for now it's open-ended hence I'll have to make my own decision on this, again thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RavenDanish Its not so much that we haven't thought about it, so much as there is no real benefit to standardizing, and lots of benefit to specializing. What would a standard give you to outweight the advantage of having a format that fits in with your languages syntax and is tuned for your languages symantics?

Comment: @Thomas maybe I was trying to find standardization so that a program can be made on the fly if parts of it are available in any of the language code-bases and that we can only know if the interface is written in some standard like iot but now I realize it's still way more subjective, so I'll take this post down

Answer (score 1):

This has interested me as well ever since I discoverede first "literate programs" and then Bird Style first in Miranda and then Haskell.   See https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming#Bird_Style

To make a long story short, we ended up using AsciiDoc which is very similar to Markdown but has a very useful feature, namely being able to include tagged regions from files - https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/include-tagged-regions/ which allows us to include live source code snippets.  The IntelliJ and Visual Studio Code plugins renders this automatically - unfortunately Github supports AsciiDoc but not this particular feature.

This allows us to have a README-foo.adoc file that dynamically pulls out source snippets in context *when rendered* and then full documentation can be provided there.   This has worked very well for us so far.   For sources the asciidoc file can be put in the same folder as the sources documented, and then the root README.adoc can link to these as needed.